# "Two Way Call communications" Private-voice-communication create-a-call Nexmo Number Using (php/Laravel/Voice API)

Tags: php, laravel

Anybody help me for the following requirements.
i want to make call from web application(PHP/Laravel) to any mobile number from (purchased Nexmo Number). Its like two way communications call.

The scenario assume in the web application(PHP/Laravel) page display the call driver options placed the call icon.
Once customer click the call icon then call to driver number from (purchased Nexmo Number).

i have some doubts, 
**how the customer can able to speak with driver from web application once click the call icon ?. 
Here we need any headphones or speaker connect with computer/laptop from web application once click the call icon to connect speak with driver mobile phone ?.**

i checked with the nexmo voice API here one way communication only working fine for me.
For example, text to speech call works for me, the above voice API code run the call automatically reached to destination number from (purchased Nexmo Number).

```
    'api_key' => '',
    'api_secret' => '',
    'to' => '14083934444',
    'from' => '16169281703',
    'text' => 'Hi Good Morning. How are you. What about you.'    
];
$url = 'https://api.nexmo.com/tts/json?' . http_build_query($params);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

In Nexmo, private-voice-communication create-a-call not clearly explained about "Two Way call communications". Kindly help me any one suggestion or provide the sample code using (php/Laravel/API) based to implement the private-voice-communication create-a-call "Two Way communications" from web application to mobile phone.
For marketplace scenarios such as food delivery or taxi and passenger communications, it is useful for users to be able to communicate with one another without exposing their phone numbers.
[private-voice-communication](https://developer.nexmo.com/use-cases/private-voice-communication#create-a-call)

Comment: Are you getting any solution please add in answer.